# How to 'copy and paste' an element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm making a simple lightbox. If you click on an image, it takes that image and shows it full screen with a black background behind it.

Here is my code:

```
$('.theContent img').live('click', function(e) {
    var lbImg = $(this);
    $('#lb').toggle();
    $('#lb').find("#lbImg").append(lbImg);           

)
```

Thing is, it takes away the variable lbImg and puts it in the lightbox. I dont want that, i just want to copy that bit of info and duplicate, rather than reposition. How would you go about that?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to append one jQuery element already in the DOM to another element?](/q/6364633/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone) method to copy the element:

```
var lbImg = $(this).clone();
```

Normally, when an element is re-appended, it is removed from the previous location. When an element have to be appended without removing it from the previous spot, it has to be duplicated.